# How to handle data returned from thread functions in main function in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python script where I have created a thread. Below is the code snippet

```
stop_thread = False
get_data = False
status = ""
subject_id = ""


def get_data_function():
    global stop_thread
    global get_data 
    global status
    global subject_id

    while stop_thread is False:
        if get_data:
            # SOME CODE
            # SOME MORE CODE
            (status, subject_id) = tive.extract_data()

            get_data = False

        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    global stop_thread
    global get_data 
    global status
    global subject_id

    thread = Thread(target=get_data_function)
    thread.start()
    res_dict = dict()
    while True:
        # SOME CODE
        # SOME MORE CODE

        if some_condition:
            get_data = True

            res_dict['status'] = status
            res_dict['subject_id'] = subject_id

        # SOME CODE
        # SOME MORE CODE
```

In above code I have defined a thread and its function `get_data_function()`. This function calls `tive.extract_data()` which gives `status, subject_id`. I have defined these variables as global so that once we have the value of these variables , I can use it in `main` function.

In `main` function, after `some_condition` is `True` we need to get the values of `status` and `subject_id` so I set global variable `get_data` as `True` which enables the `get_data_function` main code and returns the data but the problem is that `tive.extract_data()` takes 2-3 secs to respond due to which `res_dict['status'] = status` and `res_dict['subject_id'] = subject_id` in main function gives error for that 2-3 secs and after that it starts working fine.

Is there any other way of handling the values of these variables in optimized way so that until we don't have values for these variables, we don't get errors. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a thread class. I have bad experience using globals.

```
# ==================================================================================
class ThreadGetData(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stop_thread = False
        self.get_data = False
        self.status = ""
        self.subject_id = ""
        self.data_present = False

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_data_function(self):

        if self.get_data:
            # SOME CODE
            # SOME MORE CODE
            (self.status, self.subject_id) = tive.extract_data()
            self.data_present = True
            self.get_data = False

        time.sleep(1)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_thread:
            self.get_data_function()



# ==================================================================================
def main():

    thread = ThreadGetData()
    thread.start()

    res_dict = dict()
    while True:
        # SOME CODE
        # SOME MORE CODE

        if some_condition:
            thread.get_data = True

       if thread.data_present:
            res_dict['status'] = thread.status
            res_dict['subject_id'] = thread.subject_id
            self.data_present = False

        # SOME CODE
        # SOME MORE CODE
```

Comment: But how are you passing `status` and `subject_id` from thread to main function because in your answer its not global. I think this will give error. Also I cannot put `time.sleep(1)` as there are other codes also running which will be freezed everytime `thread.get_data` is called. Isn't it right.?

Comment: You can access your 'globals' using thread.status etc... I have made some edits in the example so see how it is now. I have remove sleep and use a while loop now waiting for the data. It is up to you how to structure your program with sleep or while loops. Just do some experimenting to get the feeling for it.

Comment: Ok. I see you have a continuous while True loop that you don't want to interrupt while waiting. I have added thread.data_present that indicates the data is collected. Now the loop should run without any delays. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me what does `def run(self):` means in class.

Comment: Also dont you think this line `(status, subject_id) = tive.extract_data()` should be this `(self.status, self.subject_id) = tive.extract_data()` ?

Comment: It is the 'main thread' function that is going to run when you call thread.start(). When this function exits the the thread is finished.In your case when self.stop_thread becomes True. Keep in mind that I couldn't test the example so some debugging could be required.

Comment: Yes. You're right: self.status, self.subject_id. As I said: some debugging required :-)).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Python 3's `asyncio` module, and use a coroutine instead of a thread. You can then move all of the operations that can be done before you need the value that the first coroutine returns into a second coroutine. Then, use `asyncio.gather()` to run both coroutines in parallel, waiting until both are finished.

Here is a simple example which demonstrates this pattern:

```py
import asyncio
import datetime

async def main():
    print("Starting at " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    values = await asyncio.gather(get_value(3), do_other_stuff())
    print("Received: " + str(list(values)[0]))
    print("Finished at " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

async def get_value(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return n*10

async def do_other_stuff():
    print("doing things 1")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("doing things 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("doing things 3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```